# onKey not triggering when backspace keyboard button click android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using the `OnKeyListener` on a `EditText` on Android to identify when the backspace(delete) of the keyboard was pressed and handle myself the deletion of the character(doing this because it's a field that were synchronized with external service).
Some people said to use the `TextWatcher` and handle in one of the textchanged events. While this can be a viable solution. I still trying to do it with the `onKey`.

The problem is that the `onKey` is only triggered when there is not text(empty) in the `EditText` and pressed backspace. If there's text the `onKey` is not triggered until it deletes all text.

Anyone What I am missing for the  `onKey` to be triggered in all the clicks in the backspace?

This is my xml:

```
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/trackpad_speller_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

and I am setting the listener on the fragment

```
 this.spellerInput.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

And my OnKey

```
 @Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (presenter.getSpellerType() == SpellerType.FREE_SPELLER) {
            Log.d(TAG, "backspace pressed and ignored for FREE_SPELLER");
            return false;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "backspace pressed for SEARCH_SPELLER");
            presenter.deleteChar();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way, but I found that setting the `setInputType` of the `EditText` `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` solves the problem and makes the `onKey` be triggered in all backspace clicks.

```
spellerInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Hope it helps